# Using pointer with multiple offsets in C#

Tags: c#, pointers, offset, cheat-engine

I have a CheatEngine script

```
game.exe+2F6D0E8]+478]+560]+198]+60]+470
```

And I want to use it in C #

```
            long num = MemoryHelper.ReadMemory<long>(MemoryHelper.BaseAddress + 0x2F6D0E8, 8, false);
            num = MemoryHelper.ReadMemory<long>(num + 0x470, 8, false);
            num = MemoryHelper.ReadMemory<long>(num + 0x60, 8, false);
            num = MemoryHelper.ReadMemory<long>(num + 0x198, 8, false);
            num = MemoryHelper.ReadMemory<long>(num + 0x560, 8, false);
            num = MemoryHelper.ReadMemory<long>(num + 0x478, 8, false);

            Debug.WriteLine("Offset" + num);
```

But it returns 0, what im doing wrong?

Comment: Are the offsets reversed between the script and code for a reason? Also, are the offsets in hex or decimal? There is a curious lack of A..F characters.

Comment: Im not sure that I understand your question correctly, but the value I need changes every time I enter the game.

Comment: In the command line the order is 2F6D0E8,478,560,198,60,470. In the program the order is 2F6D0E8,470,60,198,560,478 - is this reversal intentional?

Comment: Also, in the command-line, are _all_ the values in hex?

Comment: tried both sequences
all values in long, like 1900081523408

Answer (score 0):

Everything broke just on the last offset, you had to use it separately. Like

```
        long num = MemoryHelper.ReadMemory<long>(MemoryHelper.BaseAddress + 0x2F6D0E8, 8, false);
        num = MemoryHelper.ReadMemory<long>(num + 0x470, 8, false);
        num = MemoryHelper.ReadMemory<long>(num + 0x60, 8, false);
        num = MemoryHelper.ReadMemory<long>(num + 0x198, 8, false);
        num = MemoryHelper.ReadMemory<long>(num + 0x560, 8, false);
        //num = MemoryHelper.ReadMemory<long>(num + 0x478, 8, false);

        Debug.WriteLine("Offset" + (num + 0x478);
```